# Executing a command in unison before its closes the ssh connection

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, unison

[Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/)  is a file-synchronization tool that works over ssh. It accepts configurations in profile (`.prf`) files. I use an alias

```
unison my-pref.prf && ssh sameuser@sameserver.fr 'cat toto'
```

Hence I have to type my password twice. Do you know any way to execute a command on the remote host "before" unison closes the ssh session?

Comment: What does this have to do with `bash`?

Comment: Unless `unison` has hooks to do that in its configuration, probably not. You could maybe play with how it calls `ssh` and make it call a script that calls `ssh` and then does something else, but strictly speaking, it would still do the "something else" after the `ssh` connection is already closed (as does your attempt at an alias). Oh, and you could use `ssh-agent` to avoid having to manually provide your password...

Answer (score 4):

It looks like that you just want to avoid entering your password twice, so you could set up [ssh with a public/private keys](http://www.ece.uci.edu/~chou/ssh-key.html) to avoid typing your password at all.

Then you would just have to evoke ssh with the keyfile that you make:

```
ssh -i keyfile sameuser@sameserver.fr 'cat toto'
```

And you would have to add this option to your unison profile (`.prf`):

```
sshargs = -i keyfile
```